# jmeter insert jdbc request error: Invalid data type: int

Tags: jmeter

I'm run insert jdbc request from csv file in Jmeter.sql is:

```
INSERT INTO SZ_1E_MYSQL1 (TS_15M,MSISDN,IMEI,IMSI, MCC, MNC, LAC, CELL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

I set Parameter values is:

```
${TS_15M},${MSISDN},${IMEI},${IMSI},${MCC},${MNC},${LAC},${CELL}.
```

Parameter types:

```
varchar,bigint,bigint,bigint,int,int,int,bigint. Table Structure：

mysql> desc SZ_1E_MYSQL1;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TS_15M | varchar(17) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| MSISDN | bigint      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| IMEI   | bigint      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| IMSI   | bigint      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| MCC    | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| MNC    | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LAC    | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CELL   | bigint      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but test resultis：
Invalid data type: int

Thanks!  I modify it to INTEGER data type. but get another error: Invalid data type: VARCHAR(17).

Request body:

[Prepared Update Statement]

```
INSERT INTO SZ_1E_MYSQL4 (TS_15M,MSISDN,MCC,MNC,LAC,CELL,HOST,URI,L7REQ,L7REP,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,CILENTBYTE,SERVERBYTE,CLIENTFIRSTSEC,SERVERFIRSTSEC ,CLIENTLASTSEC,SERVERLASTSEC,CLIENTIPTO,SERVERIPTO,CLIENTIP,SERVERIP) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
2021/1/29 ,14171138121,460,26,96079244,84548213,DaEpVTEZRErrchtJZbKg ,uPTSXECeNNbiHCZXMNRPCMXNXoqaFtxjJqYtuRcvsOHazXZFMndqxWECTDRpBffOgJEBnGjOZTEGygRsVCjAZhSMYpPchvvYMYXWTsKkoKkfDYTeMjJSYaKRACrYtEofGZDVkxRCEDXEfUBehsmyDbXgbwwXHAMvmoZUosfbRavJEJSYqfPBVHOINqcPfEXxpUstCurU,ckDNXSPRRNGBbzEBJbTg,MnAXzPmEtROHAEpAUqbi,SvhCWBqZIsao ,fgLwLqMYhXUc,${CILENTBYTE },165230,976465,658595 ,311940,239175,KyyJeNNNXXzIsbjhmUdx,dqANPDDbsScnLCnISabp,vpOXhVroqWxhBdYfELYP,HkChRZNSERISRPuEFHbS
VARCHAR(17),BIGINT,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,BIGINT,VARCHAR(128),VARCHAR(10240),VARCHAR(1024),VARCHAR(1024),VARCHAR(16),VARCHAR(16),BIGINT,BIGINT,BIGINT, BIGINT,BIGINT,BIGINT, VARCHAR(128), VARCHAR(128),VARCHAR(128),VARCHAR(128)
```

Parameter types:

```
VARCHAR(17), BIGINT,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,BIGINT,VARCHAR(128),VARCHAR(10240),VARCHAR(1024),VARCHAR(1024),VARCHAR(16),VARCHAR(16),BIGINT,BIGINT,BIGINT, BIGINT,BIGINT,BIGINT, VARCHAR(128), VARCHAR(128),VARCHAR(128),VARCHAR(128)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is `int` data type in MySQL, most probably it's `INTEGER`

Take a look at [Java, JDBC, and MySQL Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)

[image]

More information:

- [MySQL data types](https://zetcode.com/mysql/datatypes/)
- [Using JDBC Sampler in JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733769-Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter)

Comment: Thanks!  I modify it to INTEGER data type. but get another error: Invalid data type: VARCHAR(17).

Comment: Do you see any `VARCHAR(17)` in the table or link I referenced?